# SQL Transaction Log Full when running ShrinkFile SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-backups, transaction-log

I am having an issue with DB Log Full and going through all the things trying to figure out why this is happening. I have of course implemented the backup here.

I run the backup commands for the shrink of the database log, the odd thing is that sometimes the script runs and at other times I get an error.

```
  USE [MYDB]; 
  BACKUP DATABASE [MYDB] TO DISK = 'L:\Backup\MYDB_DB_2023_01_05__T08_10_21.bak' ; 
  BACKUP LOG [MYDB] TO DISK = 'L:\Backup\MYDB_log_2023_01_05__T08_10_21.bak'  WITH INIT;  
  ALTER DATABASE [MYDB] 
  SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;  
  DBCC SHRINKFILE(MY_Log, 3000); 
  ALTER DATABASE [MYDB] 
  SET RECOVERY FULL;
```

I have no idea why I am seeing the error message below since I am running this to backup / truncate the Log.
My DB Log size is set to 3GB & Autogrow with Limit 7GB, SQL Express version is 2017

Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.  ***[I don't know why this occurs]***

Processed 894794 pages for database 'MYDB', file 'MY_Log' on file 1.
BACKUP LOG successfully processed 894794 pages in 97.732 seconds (71.528 MB/sec).

(1 row affected)
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

(1 row affected)
Msg 9002, Level 17, State 2, Line 4
The transaction log for database 'MYDB' is full due to 'LOG_BACKUP'.

***/ Yes I know the Log is full that is why I am running this script! //***

EDIT: Comment Requested Info.

[image: SQL Query Result: SELECT [name], log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases;]

Comment: Do you really need to be in full recovery mode?

Comment: I am part of a collective - so the powers that be ..  I do not understand why I have the error message or why I have the abnormal termination of the db backup.

Comment: Probably because the log is full and a non copy-only full backup updates the differential base, which is a logged change to the database.  Try backing up the log first.

Comment: Ah - that is making sense to me - as there is a process by a cohort in the collective to do these daily backups through another software services application. I can't add my dblog handling into that and neither can he. I get my log to fill up probably because he does his backups everyday.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - sorry I meant to paste in COPY_ONLY
 I tried to do the WITH COPY_ONLY but then I get BACKUP LOG cannot be performed because there is no current database backup.

Comment: Hmm.  Why is the log full? What does this return for the database:
`SELECT name, log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases;`


https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/03/my-favorite-system-column-log_reuse_wait_desc/

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - the result is now posted - but I am thinking maybe you would like that I run the query when the error is generated.

Comment: If log reuse is not blocked, then the log shouldn't grow any more, and you should be able to shrink the log file.